# Identifying valid input of character in a string, or array Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

We were asked to check following inputs from a string in every line example

```
A = B + C
A = 3 + C + 99
B = ( ( 4 + B ) + D )
```

Now the consideration that these strings would be wrong are

```
+ - :: if two operator are next together
A B :: IF two letters are next together
1 2 :: if two numbers are next together
all numbers must be integer
Letters must only be A B or C
the parenthesis should have endings... ( ) not like ( (
```

Now what I think one of the solutions are the if else and using `isdigit`, `isalpha` and checking the character that are right next to each other if they are the same character type isdigit,isspacechar,isalpha example if this is the (currently checking [1][3]) `array[1][5] = ['A','=','B','+','C']` it would look like as if `['A','=','B'/*checking*/,'+','C'/*checking*/]`

since the input is from a text file i'm doing this

```
fR = new FileReader("input.txt");
bR = new BufferedReader(fR);
Inp = new Scanner(fR);
x=0;
while(Inp.hasNextLine()) {
    int y=0;
    while(Inp.hasNextLine()) {
        stringarray[x][y];              
        y++;
    }
    x++;
}
```

How am I suppose to do it?
Or should I just stick with array char but again I don't know how to skip the spaces.. so that would go to a different discussion I guess.. I have no idea how to do the parenthesis part.

Comment: i got most of it now. but there are still rules that I couldn't apply

Answer (score 0):

Talking about skipping spaces use the trim() method using a dot connector to remove the whitespaces of both side of the string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these are two separate questions.

1) How to read the file contents and create something to loop over in your program
2) How to perform checking

For (1) I would suggest something like

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
fR = new FileReader("input.txt");
bR = new BufferedReader(fR);
inp = new Scanner(fR);
try {
    while(inp.hasNextLine()){
        lines.add(imp.nextLine());
    }
    imp.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and for (2)

```
String regex = "<regex for checking goes here>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("");

for (String l : lines) {
    if (matcher.reset(s).matches()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

You can test regex strings online here: https://regex101.com/

It may take a while to get the string right